# AgularJS ng-repeat without repeating parent elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I bassically want to do is the following:

I have two columns and I want to fill them with data with a single ng-repeat but without repeating the columns themselves. I think that it may not be possilbe, but I had to try :)

```
->Start ng-repeat="item in items"
<div exclude-from-repeat class="col1"> -> append {{item.Name}} here </div>
<div exclude-from-repeat class="col2"> -> append {{item.Description}} here </div>
->End ng-repeat
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to repeat?

Comment: Sounds like you want an ng-repeat in each of the columns but then with only one ng-repeat directive? Can you provide a sample object and html response that you'd want to achieve?

Comment: You can use ng-repeat-start to output a different elements in the same repeat, but I don't think that will fit your requirements for this. You could use a wrapper <span> with the ng-repeat on it, inside each column - but that would be two repeats and introduce the extra markup. To get exactly what you want, I think you need to write a directive.

Comment: Well I have a list of objects having different properties. I want each of these properties in a different column with the ability to hide the entire column with a single hide command on the column. Right now I have a table with <th> and <td> but I don't want to hide every single td because it's causing performance issues when I have more rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="col{{$index}}">{{item}}</div>
```

I know it's not what you asked for, but it does assign a different class to each column. The `$index` in `ng-repeat` goes from 0 to `items.length-1`

You could also try to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to have more flexibility. But in general, I do not think it is possible to exclude the parent element from the `ng-repeat` loop.